# Reading web service response using ColdFusion

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Header>
    <WSResponseHeader xmlns="http://cio.xxx.com/commonheader/v3" xmlns:ns2="http://newhorizon.xxx.com/ABCservice">
        <WSCorrelationId>?</WSCorrelationId>
    </WSResponseHeader>
</S:Header>
<S:Body>
    <ns2:newOrderResponse xmlns="http://cio.XXX.com/commonheader/v3" xmlns:ns2="http://newhorizon.XXXX.com/ABCservice">
        <ns2:ABCOrderResponse>
            <ns2:headerStatus>ERROR</ns2:headerStatus>
            <ns2:lineResponse>
                <ns2:sourceSystemRefLineNum>1</ns2:sourceSystemRefLineNum>
                <ns2:lineStatus>ERROR</ns2:lineStatus>
                <ns2:lineError>
                    <ns2:errorCode>122</ns2:errorCode>
                    <ns2:errorMessage>Billing Category Code is required.  </ns2:errorMessage>
                </ns2:lineError>
            </ns2:lineResponse>
        </ns2:ABCOrderResponse>
    </ns2:newOrderResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I have a soap web service code in ColdFusion which invokes an external web service and my app will pass some rows to it. The above is the format of response that the application will send back. There can be multiple  `<ns2:lineResponse>` type blocks. Some blocks will have error tags, some may have success tags.

How can I iterate through this response to extract details from error tag blocks only?
When I try to make loops, it is counting `<ns2:headerStatus>ERROR</ns2:headerStatus>` also as child node.

Comment: Do a search using XPath and `XmlSearch()` would seem to work well for this